# Methods of finding the line of intersection of two planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've experienced some confusion regarding the method to finding the line of intersection between two planes. I am aware of the method involving the cross product of the two plane's normal vector however my textbook seem to suggest that the line can also be found through solving the 2 equations of the plane and setting one of the variable as lambda to find the equation of the line.

$ \Pi_1: 3x-y+z=2 $

$ \Pi_2: x+2y-z=-1 $

$3x-y+z+x+2y-z=4x+y=1$, letting $x=\lambda$,

$y=1-4\lambda$, and so $\lambda+2(1-4\lambda)+1=z$;

$\therefore x=0+\lambda; y=1-4\lambda; z=3-7\lambda$

$r=(0,1,3)+\lambda(1,-4,-7)$

The answer I got at the end was slightly different from the textbook's answer, wondering if what I did was the correct way?

Comment: Show us your answer.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to parametrize a line.  Check that yours passes through two points of the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: adding the two given equations we obtain:$$4x+y=1$$ or $$x=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{y}{4}$$ plugging this in the second equation we get $$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{y}{4}+2y-z=-1$$ thus $$y=\frac{3}{7}+4z$$ plugging this in the second equation above and we get $$x=\frac{1}{7}-z$$ and $$y=\frac{3}{7}+4z$$ and $$z=z$$

Comment: That's the answer given in the textbook, though is my answer still valid?

Comment: no, the vector after $\lambda$ the direction vector is not a multiple of $(-1,4,1)$

Comment: Is z always the one that has to be set as lambda? If not, what was wrong with my approach?